# \Z end of line reagex count finding things not at absolute end of line

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find and count all things matching a certain string/strings within a larger string. I am having trouble when it comes to counting a string that ends with ]) or ] at the very end of a string. 
Example of code below:

I have tried $ instead of \Z which returns the same result. Some searching led me to believe that \z should be only the final end of the string, but it returns an error about an unexpected exit.

```
    import pandas as pd

    test= {'s':[')-[#8]-[#6]-[#8])-[#7]', '-[#6]-[#8])-[#8]']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = test)
    All = df['s'].str.count('-\[#8\]\)|\Z')
    print(All)
```

I should count 1 instance of '-[#8])|\Z' using count in the first row and 2 instances in the second row as I want to find -[#8]) or -[#8] only at the end of a string but not -[#8]-. However I find 2 instances in both rows.

Comment: To find `-[#8]-` or  `-[#8]` at the end of the string use `r'-\[#8]-?\Z'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern `-\[#8\]\)|\Z` You will either match `-\[#8\]\)` or `\Z` which will match 2 times for both rows. See [demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/H80QEz/1) and [demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/2ZeHQu/1).

You want to match either `-[#8])` or  `-[#8]` only at the end of a string. You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) for `\)` or `\Z` instead.

```
-\[#8\](?:\)|\Z)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ONUDLf/1)

Comment: That works thanks! Just so I understand, is the (?:| there to group the second part somehow?

Answer (score -1):

Just use a *Negative Boundary*.

`-\[\#8\](?![^)])`

https://regex101.com/r/t7WDjH/1

Explained:

```
 - \[ \#8 \] 
 (?!              # Below must have either FAILURE for negative assertion
                  # to pass.
                  # =======================================
      [^)]             # Requires a character
                       # -----------------
                       # No-character ahead ? : FAILURE at end of string
                       #     because there is no character.
                       # -----------------
                       # Yes-character ahead ? : FAILURE if the next character is a ')`
                       #     because ')' is not allowed
 )
```